# c# - entity framework with SqlServerCe.3.5 - Connection exception

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

i have problem with entity framework with SqlServerCe.3.5 connection.
i have small project called Assets with .SDF database and entity(the model name is Main).
now,when i'm trying to connect to the entity happend something weird.
in the first time everything works fine but now i had must to added this:

```
 if (edmConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
  {
    edmConnection.Open();
  }
```

because the connection to the entity all time was closed.
after i added this lines,i can reach to the database and the entity,but i got this message:

> The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

this is the stack Trace:

> at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
>      at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName)
>      at BL.Model.DBEntities..ctor() in C:\Users\Orel\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Assets\BL\Model\Main.Designer.cs:line 34
>      at BL.Handlers.mModelHandler..ctor()
>      at BL.Handlers.mModelHandler.GetOnlyInstance() in C:\Users\Orel\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Assets\BL\Handlers\mModelHandler.cs:line 30

this is my code and the app.config:

```
   private static mModelHandler _mInstance = null;
public static DBEntities m_context = null;


public static mModelHandler GetOnlyInstance()
{
    if (_mInstance == null)
    {
        try
        {
            m_context = new DBEntities(GetConnectionString());
            _mInstance = new mModelHandler();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


            throw;
        }

    }
    return _mInstance;
}

public static EntityConnection GetConnectionString()
{
    try
    {
        var filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        if (filePath == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filePath");

        if (filePath.EndsWith("\\Assets\\bin\\Debug"))
        {
            filePath = filePath.Replace("\\Assets\\bin\\Debug", "\\BL\\DB.sdf");
        }
        var sqlCeConnectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0}", filePath);

        // Create an EDM connection
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entity = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

        entity.Metadata = "res://*/Model.Main.csdl|res://*/Model.Main.ssdl|res://*/Model.Main.msl";
        entity.Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5";
        entity.ProviderConnectionString = sqlCeConnectionString;

        var edmConnectionString = entity.ToString();
        var edmConnection = new EntityConnection(edmConnectionString);
        if (edmConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            edmConnection.Open();
        }
        return edmConnection;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

the app.config:

```
<add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Main.csdl|res://*/Model.Main.ssdl|res://*/Model.Main.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string='Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB.sdf'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

i read in the fourm that the problem can be that the app.config and the connection string are not match,i tried this also and it dosen't work..

i just added an image of this:
[Link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/99/69123223.png/)

Help!

Orel

Comment: Could you not use the auto-generated config/connection string that the EF designer comes up with?

Comment: i used the auto-generated config/connection,my problm is in the code not in the app.config

Answer (score 0):

I think your connection string isn't being parsed correctly. Try using `&quot;` in place of the `'`.

I also believe that, for SqlCE, the `provider` within the quotes should be `provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe,3.5;` instead of `provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;`.

Notice the `,` just before the version `3.5`.

Putting it all together, we have:

```xml
<add name="DBEntities"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Main.csdl|res://*/Model.Main.ssdl|res://*/Model.Main.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe,3.5;provider connection string= &quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB.sdf&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no,it's not help.i tried this,but get notice that in the function **Getconnection** there is the line:
entity.Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5";
i tried to change this also to:
entity.Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe,3.5" 
and i got another execption

Comment: What exactly was the exception? And, it seems odd to me that you're using custom code to read the app.config values. Choose either to let your .edmx file use the auto-generated connection string in app.config or specify the connection explicitly in code. Don't do both - that might be the underlying reason for your issue